# Read From CherryPy Request Body Twice

Tags: python, cherrypy

I am running into an issue where I need to read the body of a cherrypy request a second time if there are any errors while completing the request. The code below shows my problem. I need to be able to get the full content of the body on the second call of 'read'.

```
body_length = int(cherrypy.request.headers['Content-Length'])

data1 = cherrypy.request.body.read(body_length)
print len(data1)

// 338

data2 = cherrypy.request.body.read(body_length)
print len(data2)

// 0
```

I've tried seek, but it doesn't seem like the cherrypy RequestBody object shares the same functions as the python file like object. How can I read the body of the request a second time?

Comment: May I ask why do you need to read the raw body? CherryPy tries to wrap the raw body and there isn't a good interface to do direct reading (it make sense when you have a big multi-part body), it can be done, but you'll need to have a custom body processor or a tool hooked to `before_request_body`. If is json what you need, there is a tool for that.

Comment: Yes, I do just need it in json. I'm just sticking the raw data into json.loads immediately after I get it.

Answer (score 0):

If json is the only thing that you need from the body, then maybe the [json tool](https://cherrypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#dealing-with-json) is enough for your situation.

Example:

```
class Root:

    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.tools.json_in()
    def index(self):
        data = cherrypy.request.json # already in the form of a dict
```

There are multiple ways to configure the tools some other examples can also be seen here in an [old post from my blog.](https://blog.joel.mx/posts/cherrypy-101-method-dispatcher)